# Private method invocation using Powermock

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I am unable to get the data I set to a mocked object using method invocation i.e `invokeMethod`. I am able to get it using `getInternalState`.

```
controller_mock = mock(MyController.class);

ArrayList<BaseItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

final ItemTypeOne item1 = new ItemTypeOne();
final ItemTypeOne item2 = new ItemTypeOne();
final ItemTypeTwo item3 = new ItemTypeTwo();
final ItemTypeTwo item4 = new ItemTypeTwo();

items.add(item1);
items.add(item2);
items.add(item3);
items.add(item4);

Whitebox.setInternalState(controller_mock, "mItems", items);

System.out.println(controller_mock);
//Prints -> myController
System.out.println(Whitebox.getInternalState(controller_mock, "mItems"));
//Prints -> [UNKNOWN, UNKNOWN, UNKNOWN, UNKNOWN]
System.out.println(Whitebox.invokeMethod(controller_mock, "getItems"));
//Prints -> []
System.out.println(controller_mock.getItems());
//Prints -> []
```

**getItems() In MyController**

```
public List<BaseItem> getItems() {
    return mItems;
}
```

Comment: Having the test know about the internal state of an object can lead to brittle tests. Any time you'll want to change the way things work internally, your test will break. Instead, test things from the perspective of the API your object exposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need make a choice between:

- mock method `Whitebox.invokeMethod(controller_mock, "getItems");`
- getter of the real instance `controller_mock.getItems();`

### Whitebox#invokeMethod

From the doc of [`Whitebox#invokeMethod`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-reflect/1.6.4/org/powermock/reflect/Whitebox.html#invokeMethod-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-):

> Invoke a private or inner class method. This might be useful to test
>   private methods.

It works only if private:

```
private List<BaseItem> getItems() {
    return mItems;
}
```

In this case you are only allowed to call the getter in the test class since it's private.

### controller_mock.getItems()

Mocking means creating objects that simulate the behavior of real objects. Since `controller_mock` is enhanced by mockito, if you want to call the method of the real instance, you need set it explicitly:

```
when(controller_mock.getItems()).thenCallRealMethod();
System.out.println(controller_mock.getItems());
```

Comment: Okay, so I changed the `mock(MyController.class)` to `new MyController()` i.e creating a real object, used Whitebox to set the private fields, then calling `getItems()` gave the right results. Thanks!